# macのpathを更新する。

Tags: macos, homebrew, makefile

```
brew install make
```

にてGNU makeをインストールしました。

```
which make
/usr/local/bin/make
```

であり、
    /usr/local/bin/make --version
とすると
GNU Make 4.2.1 
となりますが、

```
make --version
```

とすると
GNU Make 3.81 
となってしまいます。

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

なので、パスは通っているはずです。

mac付属のコマンドより優先度を上げるにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 環境変数 PATH が `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:` となっていて、最後の文字が `:`(コロン) になっていますが、これは書き間違いではなく、実際にそうなっているという事でよろしいでしょうか。また、`type make` を実行するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

brewでインストールした`make`はmacOSにバンドルされたものと衝突を防ぐために`gmake`という名前になっています。
インストールしたものを使いたければ`gmake`を利用してください。